# MD5 duplicate removing errors

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob              

for i in $2; do
  md5sum=$(md5sum -q "$file")        
  echo "-- Found: $file ($md5sum)"
  for duplicate in $2; do
    if [[ "$md5sum" = "$(md5sum -q "$duplicate")" ]]; then
      rm -v "$duplicate"
    fi
  done
done
```

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a directory in linux, I call this script using

```
source  ~/my-applications/bin/remdup
```

but the errors I got was that the md5 command was not found and it could not find the duplicate directory, any tips?
also I have very little experience with linux so this code was made up of trying to piece together things I have learned over the internet, so any tips are welcome.
the script this gets called from is shell, and this is a bash so I don't know if that would change anything

EDIT: has to change somethings to $2 because its carrying variables over from the other script
EDIT:changed line 7 md5 to md5sum

Comment: Have you installed the md5 command?  For me it is `md5sum`, not `md5`.

Comment: literally just changed that there :)

Comment: I see ;)  Please paste the error message.  You should not `source` that script but call it: `bash ~/my-applications/bin/remdup` or give it execute permissions: `chmod a+x ~/my-applications/bin/remdup` and then you can call it directly: `~/my-applications/bin/remdup`

Comment: I think `i` is not accessible via `$file`.

Comment: I'm using a vm machine, the errors are as follows -q is an invalid option, and it still can't remove the duplicate, maybe it is linking back to how I haven't got md5sum working yet

Comment: You might want to add a check to prevent comparing a file with itself, otherwise your script will remove all files because each is equal to itself ;-)

Comment: Btw, what is `$1` holding?  You are just using `$2`.

Comment: how would I add something like that? and what do you mean I is not accessible to file, should I rename all files to i?

Comment: No, that was a joke because you loop with variable `i` and then try to use `$file` instead of `$i` inside the loop.  Looks like a simple mistake.

Comment: $1 is holding source information, because it comes from a copying script, $2 is the destination and I only want to remove the files from there

Comment: If your `md5sum` does not know the option `-q` (mine also does not), then you should not use it of course.  I think it is to prevent the filename given out along with the checksum (thus rendering it different for each file which is not wanted); if so, then you should use `md5sum < $file` instead of `md5sum $file`, then the filename always will be `-` signifying stdin.

Comment: should I use file or i? I am really wanting it to check all items in the directory

Comment: Enough comments, see my answer ;-) it's fairer to go on there.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob              

for file in "$2"/*
do
  md5sum=$(md5sum < "$file")        
  echo "-- Found: $file ($md5sum)"
  for duplicate in "$2"/*
  do
    [ "$file" = "$duplicate" ] && continue
    [ "$md5sum" = "$(md5sum < "$duplicate")" ] && rm -v "$duplicate"
  done
done
```

Comment: agh I should just be left with 25 items, stil have 28. the output says md5sum is a directory

Comment: hmm when it echoes found, it outputs the location, does that mean it doesn't go into the file?

Comment: Ah, sorry, of course you have to have a `/*` after your `$2` argument.  See my updated answer in the lines with the for loops.

Comment: alright I have fixed that error by replacing "[]" with "[[]]" but it still doesn't remove anything. I should mention some of the files get renamed when they are copied, but that shouldn't change anything because it doesn't change the md5sum number

Comment: Bash can handle the `[]` quite well, my version should not pose the problem of `unary operator expected` (and it does not when I try it here).

Comment: I guess you might have left out some double quotes?

Comment: alright, fixed it, sort of. it still claims duplicate does not exist

Comment: Please paste (or type thoroughly) the complete error message.

Comment: rm: cannot remove '&duplicate': No such file or directory

Comment: There's really a `&` in that message?  You accidentally typed a `&` instead of a `$`, didn't you?  In your source I mean

Comment: oh my that is embarrassing, but it works now :) I am so sorry you had to put up with me

Comment: I like doing that ;-)